# Ionic Issues With iOS 9 Beta

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I'm running my ionic app on the iOS 9 beta, it runs ok - but randomly when I click a button to take me to the next view, it will go to the new view and then take me back to the previous view. Sometimes when I click the back button in the header, it will take me to the previous view and then forward again.

It's working fine on the latest stable version of iOS and Android.

Is this something anyone else has experienced with iOS 9 Beta? is there a fix?

Comment: This question is perhaps better suited for their github page than stackoverflow..

Comment: There's a bug in uiWebView, used by Cordova that causes an 'infinite digest' error in AngularJS: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12241 - I'm seeing this in my Cordova + Angular app. If you run it from XCode and use the Safari web inspector to debug over USB you may well see the same runtime error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been addressed by us and the angular team.
We have created a patch that should work.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4082

http://blog.ionic.io/preparing-for-ios-9/

Comment: the issue is still there with my app even after adding the patch.Can anyone let me know what can be done